# Aggregation on nested field not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Im unable to do an aggregation on nested documents. Here are 2 of the sample documents:
document 1

```
{
  "name": "Samuel Lone",
  "assignments": [
    {
      "subject": "data structures",
      "score": 43,
      "dept": "cs"
    },
    {
      "subject": "fluid theory",
      "score": 37,
      "dept": "ec"
    }
  ]
}
```

document2

```
{
  "name": "Manya Pious",
  "assignments": [
    {
      "subject": "data structures",
      "score": 43,
      "dept": "cs"
    },
    {
      "subject": "fluid theory",
      "score": 37,
      "dept": "ec"
    }
  ]
}
```

When i give the following query for aggregation ,it results in no results.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "dept_breakdown": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "assignments.dept"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the aggregation on the field "assignments.dept" done?

Comment: Which version of ElasticSearch are you using? Are "assignments" mapped as nested fields?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064127/not-able-to-aggregate-on-nested-fields-in-elasticsearch?rq=1 - also, please always provide mapping of ElasticSearch docs when posting, it helps in pinpointing issues.

Answer (score 1):

For `nested` fields, use [nested aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html):

```
POST /your_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "nested_assignments": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "assignments"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "dept_terms": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "assignments.dept"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If this doesn't help, please post your mapping of the docs as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the field `"assignments"` is of `nested` type, then you need to use [`nested aggregations`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html). Your original query will work fine if `"assignments"` field is not of `nested` type.

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "dept_breakdown": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "assignments"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "departments": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "assignments.dept"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```